Jumping through hoops to install Sage math: is there a better way?
I need to install Sage for Python on my Windows 10 machine. This has proven more messy than I would hope; I am punished for not using Linux. My specific question is how to get GNU make's build_w32.bat to find sys/types.h in the correct location, but my general question is just how to, in modern times (older SO questions don't help me) install Sage for Python on a Windows machine.

As per instructions, I learned I could first install Anaconda and then hope to use it to install Sage. The commands on the linked website didn't work, though. Shame, but thankfully there was another set of instructions which I tried to follow.
(base) C:\Users\????>conda install conda-forge::sage
Channels:
 - defaults
 - conda-forge
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides bdw-gc >=8.0.4,<9 needed by sage-9.3-hd8ed1ab_0

Could not solve for environment specs
The following package could not be installed
└─ sage is not installable because it requires
   └─ bdw-gc >=8.0.4,<9 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel).

So apparently I have to install this third thing, bdw-gc. Ok, well I went here and downloaded the .tar.gz for a sufficiently recent version, and was rewarded with many code files but no convenient install.exe. Turns out I need to install a fourth thing, GNU make, to then run "make" on the Makefile.direct as per instructions. Oh, but if I download the most recent .tar.gz for GNU make and extract it, there's no convenient install.exe either. Instead there's a bat file which refuses to run correctly:
C:\Users\????>\Downloads\make-4.4\make-4.4>build_w32.bat

Creating GNU Make for Windows 9X/NT/2K/XP/Vista/7/8/10

**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.9.3
** Copyright (c) 2021 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29913 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]
.\WinRel\src - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
A subdirectory or file .\WinRel already exists.
A subdirectory or file .\WinRel\src already exists.
- pkg-config not found, building without Guile

Compiling .\WinRel version
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
- Compiling src/ar.c
ar.c
.\WinRel/src\config.h(553): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/types.h': No such file or directory

Googling, "cannot open sys/types.h" is a common problem. Unfortunately I could only find answers for what to do if I'm running a Visual Studio project (I have VS Community 2019 installed, incidentally) which is not the case here. How can I make this build_w32.bat, which comes with GNU make, use the correct file path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\sys\types.h?
Well, I can personally go to this erroneous WinRel/src/config.h file and edit the file path there, right? There's a problematic #include <sys/types.h> and I can edit this to #include <C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\sys\types.h> (which my version of Visual Studio recognises as a correct file path). But the gods are not smiling on me, because this doesn't work. As soon as I do this, save and then attempt to run build_w32.bat, it reverts the changes to config.h and tries to open sys/types.h in the incorrect location again. I can actually see my edited line, in VS, change before my eyes after I run build_w32.bat.
What can I do? I just want to install Sage for Python 3, any version at this point, and don't care beyond that. I have tried to do everything asked of me but now the software is shooting itself in the foot, not even letting me help it find the correct paths. And so far, I have had to install many, many auxiliary items just to do the seemingly simple act of installing a Python package. Is there a better way? For Windows?

I should think that some Python packages are indeed *nix only. Windows has good support for Linux internally though, and it is likely going to be much easier to go down that route.

https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/index.html
It is highly recommended to install SageMath by following the official guide and using WSL. The instructions you linked specifically mention that the conda-forge installation only works for Linux and macOS so I suspect that may be why you are running into issues.
